# cassandra and vault error logs

Tags: cassandra

after upgrading a node in cassandra, these error in log occured:
I want to investigate but dont have a direction, any clue will help 
thanks

```
2016/09/19 06:24:49 [INFO] core: post-unseal setup starting
2016/09/19 06:24:49 [INFO] core: mounted backend of type generic at secret/
2016/09/19 06:24:49 [INFO] core: mounted backend of type cubbyhole at cubbyhole/
2016/09/19 06:24:49 [INFO] core: mounted backend of type system at sys/
2016/09/19 06:24:49 [INFO] core: mounted backend of type cassandra at cassandra/
2016/09/19 06:24:49 [INFO] rollback: starting rollback manager
2016/09/19 06:24:50 [INFO] expire: restored 2 leases
2016/09/19 06:24:50 [INFO] core: post-unseal setup complete
2016/09/19 06:24:55 gocql: unable to dial control conn node-0.cassandra-app.mesos:9042: dial tcp 10.0.2.42:9042: getsockopt: connection refused
2016/09/19 06:25:12 error: failed to connect to 10.0.2.42:9042 due to error: gocql: no response to connection startup within timeout
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra cluster is not cross-version compatible, you can not upgrade a node only, you have to upgrade the cluster. This is a common mistake people tend to do, please see this video [here](https://academy.datastax.com/resources/diagnosing-problems-production-datastax-enterprise-and-apache-cassandra) it mentiones this problem, also it is very very useful with lots of good info.

Comment: thanks @Hasson.  so I need to finish upgrading all nodes before?

Comment: yes, you have to upgrade all your cluster, see the video in the updated answer.

Comment: but it looks like the best practice is upgrading nodes one-by-one [here](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~pg1712/blog/cassandra-cluster-rolling-upgrade/)
 for avoiding downtimes right?